# Bootstrap datepicker start date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

how to set the start date on bootstrap date picker by passing the value of declared variable?

```
var datetofill="+1d";
$('datefrom').datepicker({
     startDate: datetofill,
     endDate: "+1y"
});
```

the code works in start up but when i change the value into "+3d", the startDate not change, it is still "+1d"; all I want is to have a date that is dynamic. thanks

Comment: $('datefrom').datepicker("setStartDate", dtofill);

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to change the startDate parameter of the datepicker after it's already been created, which is what it seems you're suggesting that you want, then you should just be able to call:

```
myDatePicker.datepicker("option", { startDate: "+3d" });
```